# Wireshark HTTP Trace

Tags: http, wireshark

How do I trace the path of HTTP packets using Wireshark. When I filter out using keyword "HTTP", all I see is just the source and destination IP addresses, rather for every HTTP request I would want to see what path did it take with their IP addresses. I would like to see an output similar to traceroute.

Comment: _"I would like to see an output similar to traceroute."_ - what makes you think Wireshark can do this? See [Source and Destination Packets on Wireshark Relative or Absolute?](http://serverfault.com/questions/519426/source-and-destination-packets-on-wireshark-relative-or-absolute) on ServerFault, where it's claimed it can't.

Comment: wireshark picks up the packets at the place where you use wireshark. You use wireshark at 1 place, not at every hop between you and the server. What you ask for can't be done unless you collect the packets inbetween every router between you and the server and you know the IP address of those routers. This is impossible in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for a sniffer program to determine the full path that an IP packet took merely by looking at the packet, unless one of the IP "record route" options was used, so that the packet, as received by the program, contains the full route.  That option is rarely, if ever, set.

In addition, that wouldn't help for packets sent by the machine running the sniffer program - you have to capture packets on the final machine in order for the recorded route to have the full path.

So, no, Wireshark can't do this, tcpdump can't do this, Microsoft Network Monitor can't do this, KSniffer can't do this, NetScout Sniffer can't do this, OmniPeek can't do this, *no* sniffer can do this.